# remove bottom padding from iPhone 11

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, autolayout

In iPhone 11 I get a bottom padding that looks really bad. I can remove the padding view by view, but I have to move everything down (views and buttons that moved up b/c of that padding), which is annoying since I am working in a big app. Is there a way to remove that padding from the whole app, without having to arrange every view by code?

This is an example of how I am currently fixing the padding (and repeat for everything that got moved up b/c of said padding):

```
let padding = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.safeAreaInsets.bottom ?? 0
menuBarY.constant = 0 + padding
```

in case someone is not familiar with this particular padding, this is what happens in iPhone 11:

[image]

Comment: That padding is called safe area, and I do not recommend covering it with buttons.

Comment: i wont cover it with buttons, i move the buttons up (if it has a bottom button like the one on the image), but i do want to make to color cover that safe space so i need to make the view bigger or move the view down if there is no buttons, furthermore it does move all the views up, so any view added by code with coordinates will be in a incorrect place.

Comment: you should keep using safeArea. If you don't like gap between orange view and bottom of the screen - change your constrains to target `superview.bottom` instead of `safeArea.bottom`. But also change constraints inside orange view to make sure that buttons are above safeArea.

Comment: @Kirow that is exactly what i want to do/i am doing, i just want to avoid doing it manually for every view, specially the ones that are generated by code. thats why i want a way to remove the safe space globally and fix the views that do need fixing view by view instead of working on 40+ views that don't really need any change except moving down by that padding. instead of the 5 that have a bottom button and would need a manual fix

Comment: Use a UIToolbar. If you configure it correctly it is extended down into the curvy part of the screen automatically.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to avoid safe areas, just add another view and match the background color

```
    let view = UIView()
    view.backgroundColor = yourColor
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    superview.addSubview(view)
    //-
    view.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superview.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superview.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    view.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superview.widthAnchor).isActive = true
    view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: buttonView.topAnchor).isActive = true
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but this is not really what i asked, as i wrote on the question i know how to remove the padding, i don't know how to do it in the whole app at once, i have a lot of views and i don't want to fix it view by view

Answer (score 0):

Set this as in swift:

```
let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow!
            let viewWidth = window.frame.size.width
            let viewHeight = window.frame.size.height - window.safeAreaInsets.bottom
            let viewFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: viewWidth, height: viewHeight)
            self.view.frame = viewFrame
```